# Web Api + HTML5 (no Razor) + Angularjs + CSRF

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api

I have a pure HTML5 (no razor) with angularjs as front end and pure asp.net Web api as backend. Almost all of the examples that I see in the web-sphere handle CRSF using  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() of the built in MVC solution. Is there a way to implement CRSF without using Razor's  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()?

Thanks

Comment: this is not duplicate. I have specifically mentioned I don't want to use razor. the link above doesn't mention anything about not using razor. it only mentions that it want to use WebApi instead of MVC.

Comment: Apologies, I'd misinterpreted. Check out this instead: http://www.bitwisejourneys.com/extending-the-mvc-anti-forgery-token-concept-to-work-with-asp-net-web-api-and-angularjs/

Comment: cool. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Allen pointed out on twitter, you got a full sample here: https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/tree/dev/samples/AntiforgerySample

In Startup.cs they make sure a token is a appended to the response in a cookie, using Angular's default header name for sending the XSRF token:

```
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    if (
        string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
        string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default.
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
    }

    return next(context);
});
```

When getting the items, they're just serialized:

```
if (string.Equals("GET", context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    var items = repository.GetItems();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items));
}
```

But on the post they make sure to validate the token that is passed with the request:

```
// This will throw if the token is invalid.
await antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
```

A really minimalist sample, I'll probably blog/vlog about this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have just achieved this, also however I'm using aurelia. I didn't have to change any client side for the implementation I chose so this may or may not work for you but it may help in getting you started. Importantly I didn't have to use razor

I'm using owin and oauth for authentication so I send bearer token to the client. On a successful login I set xsrf tokens as a cookie like so:

```
string cookieToken, formToken;
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
context.Response.Headers.Append("Set-Cookie", $".XSRF-TOKEN={cookieToken}:
{formToken}; Secure; HttpOnly;");
```

where context is the owin context, this should work with httpContext also. I used the AntiForgery in System.Web.Helpers to generate the tokens. setting HttpOnly provides added protection as it makes the cookie unavailable in javascript (so long as the browser supports it)

Then I created a filter in the web api pipeline to validate the xsrf tokens. So on all future requests the .XSRF-TOKEN is sent by the browser.

The filter has the following function:

```
static void ValidateAntiForgeryToken(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var owinContext = actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"] as OwinContext;
    var xsrfTokens = owinContext.Request.Cookies[".XSRF-TOKEN"]?.Split(':');
    if (xsrfTokens == null)
    {
        throw new HttpAntiForgeryException();
    } 

    string cookieToken = xsrfTokens[0], formToken = xsrfTokens[1];
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

I get the owinContext but if you are not using owin you should be able to read the cookie from httpcontext. This isn't a perfect solution and needs work on to get it right, but it got me up and running and may help you too